# How to avoid dot collapsing on scatter plot d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection, scatter-plot

i'm a new in d3 Js universe , i created a scatter plot with json , but certain dot have the same position and i would like to put them side by side. I tried to use force collision with force simulation but nothing happenned. 
I followed many example [scatter plot with collision](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/9d9f03a0016bc9df0f13b0d52978c02f)  [collision detection](https://bl.ocks.org/d3indepth/9d9f03a0016bc9df0f13b0d52978c02f)

```
function constructScatterPoint(){

     svg = d3.select("#graphDiv").append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
         .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


        svg.append("g").attr("class", "x axis").attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")").call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)).append("text")
              .attr("class", "label")
              .attr("x", width)
              .attr("y", -6)
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("Periode")
              .attr("stroke","black");


        svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)).append("text")
              .attr("class", "label")
              .attr("x", 0)
              .attr("y", -6)
              .text("Durée")
              .attr("stroke","black");

    const forceX = d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.015)
            const forceY = d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.015)

              var force = d3.forceSimulation()
                .velocityDecay(0.2)
                .force("x", forceX)
                .force("y", forceY)
                .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d){
                  return 5 + 0.5;
                }).iterations(5))
                .nodes(data).on("tick", tickActions);

          maintenanceTaskDot=svg.selectAll("dot").data(data).enter().append("circle")
             .attr("stroke", "var(--greydark)")
             .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
              .attr("r", 5)
             .attr("fill", function(d){ if(d.maintenance_work=="A") {return "var(--purple)"}else if(d.maintenance_work=="H"){return "var(--pink)"}return "var(--cyan)"} )
             .style("opacity",0.5)
            .on('mouseover', showTaskCode.show)
             .on('mouseout',showTaskCode.hide)
            .on("click", clickOnCircle)









function tickActions(e) {
        svg.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", xValue)
             .attr("cy", yValue)

          } 

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it ! 
xValue and yValue corresponding to

```
     xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
     yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
     xValue=function(d){return xScale(d.period)};
     yValue=function(d){return yScale(d.duration)}; 



              var force = d3.forceSimulation(data)
                    .force("x", d3.forceX(xValue))
                   .force("y", d3.forceY(yValue))
                    .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(7))
                    .force("manyBody", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-5))
                    .velocityDecay(0.8)
                    .alphaTarget(0.1)
                     .on("tick", tickActions);          

         function tickActions(e) {
          maintenanceTaskDot
          .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return d.y; });

          }
```